# MVC with Autocomplete Not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I have this code that does the auto complete but apparently I am doing something wrong as it not working.

This is my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.city)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city)

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js") %>'
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: '<%: Url.Action("Location", "CityList") %>'
    });        
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public class LocationController : Controller
{
    private pEntities db = new pEntities();

    public ActionResult CityList(string city)
    {
        var results = from c in db.CityCodes
                      where c.city.StartsWith(city)
                      select new { label = c.city, id = c.city_id };
        return Json(results.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or errors? Have you inspected it under FireBug?

Comment: Though it's been a while since I used asp.net-mvc, I think it looks pretty good actually. Testing with firebug to narrow down the things that could go wrong is the best way to go. Check if the element with the city-id exists, whether UI is correctly loaded, whether the URL works that is the source of the autocomplete etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first problem was Url.Action is not getting resolved inside the javascript and the second problem like Jacob said was i had to use term.

i just used below url instead of url action.

$("#city").autocomplete({
        source: 'Location/CityList'
    });

Comment: You were using `<%:` instead of the Razor syntax.  You should be able to use `Url.Action`, just do it like this: `@Url.Action("CityList", "Location")'.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is this:

```
Url.Action("Location", "CityList")
```

[Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758.aspx) takes the action name first, and then the controller "name."  I find that counter-intuitive as well.  Do this instead:

```
Url.Action("CityList", "Location")
```

**Update:**

I've looked at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) for the jQuery autocomplete plugin, and it looks like your controller should be accepting a parameter named `term`, not `city`.  Perhaps that's the other half of the problem you're encountering.

```
public ActionResult CityList(string term)
{
    // ...
}
```